# Replacement For "Centers Polygons" Node In Blender Sverchok?

Tags: node-editor, sverchok

I keep getting asked for "Centers polygon" node in various Blender / Sverchok tutorials but I cannot find one.  Nor is there anything online that points me in the direction of it's replacement.

Can anyone tell me what node I am looking for?

Comment: has this question been edited by someone not me?

Answer (score 1):

Section analyzers has two nodes for this feature. Both have benefits, one output matrices, other has median calculation and bounds center and median weighted also.
[image]

Comment: cheers dude. i found this out yesterday but forgot i'd posted this

Comment: this Q have to be in SE with right A for others